# Changing volume capacity

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, volume

I have an Android tablet in my car, and the volume it's volume is in the range on 0-30.
It is very low since the last tablet (not an android tablet) had a range of 0-60.

How can I raise the maximum volume to 60? Will I have to root the device?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can with root, but if understood correctly I think you're wrong in the basic of your question: A device has a maximum volume (which can or cannot be achieved regularly<sup>[1]</sup>) and the possible range is being split into a numbers range that will allow you to choose.

In your case, if you'll root and be able to change the range, it will do one of the following:

1. Set every 1 current unit to two new units (like jumping in 0.5 each time).
2. Split the volume control in another way so that it's not distributed evenly.

<sup>[1]</sup> Maybe it will be possible with root to increase the maximum volume by reducing the sound quality - but that's not what your question asks.